# Does ACM ICPC rules support c++11 feature?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have searched whether ACM ICPC regional/word final rules support C++11 feature or not, but found nothing about this particular query. I am eager to know this because some of the noteworthy online judge do not support C++11 feature yet.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming, but instead about the rules of a contest

Comment: Next time, instead of wildly "searching", actually _read_. It took me literally thirty seconds to find the answer, and I'd never even heard of "ACM ICPC" before.

Answer (score 1):

Just read [the rules](https://icpc.baylor.edu/worldfinals/rules):

> #### Computing Environment
>
> The World Finals programming language tools include Java, and C/C++.  See the Programming Environment Web Site, for detailed configuration information.  Prior to the World Finals, the judges will have solved all problems in Java and C/C++.

The "[Programming Environment Web Site](https://icpc.baylor.edu/worldfinals/programming-environment)" tells you *exactly* what the code will be run on; notably, it's with the `-gnu++11` flag.